# VMWare player network won't work after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, vmware, windows-8.1

I've tried both NAT and Bridged options on both of my VM's (Windows XP and Ubuntu), but I can't connect to the internet in any case. I also tried to repair the VMWare Player instalation with no success. Screenshot of ifconfig:

[image]

Comment: Don't try to "repair" the installation.  Uninstall the application then reinstall the application.  This will be only way to get it to work.

Comment: So I reinstalled it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the virtual network adapter is active. If yes active NAT, too, and
use a static IP which is in the same IP-adress area as your native systems'.
E.g. the Hypervisors' IP is 192.168.99.55 use 192.168.99.54 or 56. 
The DHCP service might not work properly at present. 
This might help^^

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It somehow started working while playing with the adapter.